# Proving an addition function is associative using Coq

Tags: ocaml, coq, addition, associative, coq-tactic

I am trying to prove that a predefined addition function is associative, but I am stuck at the step where the goal reads

```
plus (S x') (plus y z) = plus (plus (S x') y) z
```

but the only hypothesis I have is :

```
IHx' : forall y z : nat,
plus x' (plus y z) = plus (plus x' y) z
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the definition of your function plus at this point, for instance using a function to evaluate your goal such as `cbn` (`simpl` or `lazy` may also work). Then you obtain a goal where your induction hypothesis apply so you can finish with `congruence.`

By the way, the base case when `x = 0` can be solved simply by computation so `reflexivity` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

You have proved that `plus 0 x = x`, but you can also (easily) prove that `plus (S x) y = S (plus x y)`.  If you do that, you can rewrite your goal into
`S (plus x' (plus y z)) = S (plus (plus x' y) z)` and then you can rewrite with your induction hypothesis.